# I want dont print "" in php json

Tags: php, sql, json

I get data php sql after i print from json its but i want dont print a item in "" 
i want dont print id in ""

```
require('config.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM file";
$result=$conn->query($sql);

foreach($result as $rows){

    $recordfil=array();
    $recordfil['id']=$rows['idfile'];
    // $recordfil['file']=$rows['filef'];

    $nnfile[]=$recordfil;
}

$filegen=$nnfile;

$arrayovp=[
    'ovpn_file'=>
    $filegen
];

echo json_encode($arrayovp);
?>
```

It output :

```
{"ovpn_file":[{"id":"36"},{"id":"35"}]}
```

I want only 36 or 35 without ""

Comment: Without quotes it will be __invalid json__. What's the problem with using quotes? Any __javascript__ or other programming language is capable of parsing this json string.

Comment: No I want only 36 or 35 without ""

Comment: Explicitly cast to int: `$recordfil['id'] = (int) $rows['idfile'];`

Comment: "No I want only 36 or 35 without quotes" -- do it in the client app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP supports automatically encoding numeric strings as numbers using the [`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) option, which might be easier than explicitly type-casting all relevant fields.

Try

```
echo json_encode($arrayovp, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

# {"ovpn_file":[{"id":36},{"id":35}]}
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/ANdUM